# Retrive Multiple Data Firebase in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to retrieve multiple data from firebase. I only know how to retrieve one data.

Here is my sample code.

```vb
Friend Class Employee_No_Fingerprint
    Public Property code As Integer
    Public Property last_name As String
    Public Property first_name As String
    Public Property middle_name As String
    Public Property suffix As String
    Public Property department_name As String
    Public Property picture As String
    Public Property fingerprint As String
    Public Property upload As Integer
End Class
```

```vb
Private Sub GetAllEmployee()

    Dim datEmployeeNoFingerprint As New Employee_No_Fingerprint()

    Dim response As FirebaseResponse = clientFingerprint.Get("Employee_No_Fingerprint")
    datEmployeeNoFingerprint = response.ResultAs(Of Employee_No_Fingerprint)()
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: There is an ADO.net provider available for Firebase as a Nuget package.

Comment: Hi Mary, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

Private Sub GetAllEmployee()

```
    Dim load As FirebaseResponse = client.Get("Employee_No_Fingerprint")
    Dim data As Dictionary(Of String, POJO_Export) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, POJO_Export))(load.Body.ToString())
```

End Sub